# Why is ifft2(fft2(g)) different from g in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I made an object `g` representing a plane wave through a circular aperture with a zero phase.

When I take the inverse Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of `g`, the result is different from `g` itself. The phase is very noisy.

Why? And how can I improve it?

```
import numpy as np

# object (circular aperture)
M, N = 256, 256 # resolution

D = M/2
Xo, Yo = np.ogrid[:M,:N]
r = np.sqrt( (Xo-M//2)**2 + (Yo-N//2)**2 )

amplitude = r <= D/2. # real part

g = amplitude * np.exp(1j * 0) # I set the phase at zero (imaginary part)

G = np.fft.fft2(g)

gi = np.fft.ifft2(G)
```

See attached plot:

[image: amplitude and phase of object before and after transform]

Comment: This looks like numerical noise to me.

Comment: I got ~1e-17 values which is very small for double-precision numbers regarding the input and the numerical method. Also note that `np.allclose(g, gi)` is `True`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014#588014 . Besides, the phase should be pretty sensitive to the input (if not even chaotic in this case due to the specific input).

Comment: You should not attempt to compute the phase of complex values that are very close to zero. It will be completely given by rounding errors in computations.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, gotcha. I get a value of False though for np.allclose(g, gi). I am using the spyder IDE, not sure if that has an impact of numerical level of accuracy.

Comment: It is weird that `np.allclose(gi,g)` is `false` for you (not the case for me either). The reason the `np.angle` is so different is because the absolute value is so close to zero. If the absolute value of a number is very close to zero you can expect numerical error to make a big difference in the angle. If you simply offset by doing `g = g + 1` then the resulting angle plot I get has a magnitude of no more than `1e-16`

Comment: @SimonTartakovksy, g + 1 gives indeed much more satisfying results. Thanks so much!